# kubernetes API Server could not be accessed through public IP

Tags: kubernetes

I have installed Kubernetes 1.7 single Node cluster on my Laptop. I could access the API Server at 127.0.0.1:8080 and localhost:8080 but not with my `<publicIP>:8080`..

How I could achieve this. Where I need to specify api server to map to my public IP. Please help me on this issue.

Comment: Actual error messages, ways you tried to fix it, OS, ... Details please.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `--bind-address` is set on the api server, see https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kube-apiserver/